# Android Box to play videos on two different screen

Tags: android, mobile, multiple-monitors, odroid

I am trying to develop an Android app that uses two separate monitors.
My current setup is one Odroid box connected to two different monitors with HDMI cables.
I know how to create an app with Exoplayer to play it on one monitor, but I cannot find any clues on playing different videos on each screen simultaneously.
Is this feasible? If so which class should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the feature you're looking for:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support#multi-display

Note that it will only work in Android 10+. That's because you need both screens to be in the `resumed` state if both are going to display videos simultaneously.